# How to override nuget dependencies id in nuspec file

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I have projectA and projectB in the same solution.

projectA creates its own package, but I override the package id by using a prefix:

```
 <PackageIdPrefix></PackageIdPrefix>
 <PackageId>$(PackageIdPrefix)$(MSBuildProjectName)</PackageId>
```

The command to generate the package is :

```
dotnet pack  .\$(ProjectName).csproj  --include-symbols --no-build -o C:\dev\UPP\Packages -p:PackageIdPrefix=MyPrefix."
```

Therefore the generated package name is **MyPrefix.ProjectA.nupkg**

projectB references projectA as a `project reference` since they belong to the same solution.
projectB creates its own package, in the same way:

```
   <PackageIdPrefix></PackageIdPrefix>
   <PackageId>$(PackageIdPrefix)$(MSBuildProjectName)</PackageId>
```

However in the nuspec of the generated **MyPrefix.ProjectB.nupkg** I end with :

```
  <dependency id="ProjectA" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

So the prefix was not used to create the dependency in the nuspec. Obviously this leads to an error when I try to install this package since the dependency `ProjectA` does not exist...

How can I prefix the dependency ?

Comment: Does `<dependency id="$(PackageIdPrefix)ProjectA" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />` work?

Comment: I don't know, how could I test this ? The nuspec inside the package is auto-generated by the pack command. That's actually part of the problem I guess.

Comment: if you run `dotnet clean` and `dotnet pack -p:PackageIdPrefix=Blah` on your solution, you can test by installing ProjectB

Comment: yes, that's what i'm doing. But the prefix is only added to the name of the package being packed. The prefix is not added to the dependency.